# node.js - infinite loop during JSONStream

Tags: node.js, stream, infinite-loop, jsonstream

I've got a node.js server that is freezing in production, and it appears to be caused by an infinite loop inside of JSONStream. Here's a stack trace captured from a core dump from a frozen server:

```
1: toString [buffer.js:~392] (this=0x1e28fb6d25c9 <a Buffer>#1#,encoding=0x266ee104121 <undefined>,start=0x266ee104121 <undefined>,end=0x266ee104121 <undefined>)
2: arguments adaptor frame: 0->3
3: write [/home/deploy/node_modules/JSONStream/node_modules/jsonparse/jsonparse.js:136] (this=0x32cc8dd5a999 <a Parser>#2#,buffer=0x32cc8dd5aa49 <a Buffer>#3#)
4: /* anonymous */ [/home/deploy/node_modules/JSONStream/index.js:~17] (this=0x32cc8dd5ab11 <a Stream>#4#,chunk=0x32cc8dd5aa49 <a Buffer>#3#)
5: write [/home/deploy/node_modules/JSONStream/node_modules/through/index.js:~24] (this=0x32cc8dd5ab11 <a Stream>#4#,data=0x32cc8dd5aa49 <a Buffer>#3#)
6: write [_stream_readable.js:~582] (this=0x266ee106c91 <JS Global Object>#5#,dest=0x32cc8dd5ab11 <a Stream>#4#,i=0,list=0x266ee104101 <null>)
7: flow [_stream_readable.js:592] (this=0x266ee106c91 <JS Global Object>#5#,src=0x32cc8dd5ac69 <an IncomingMessage>#6#)
8: /* anonymous */ [_stream_readable.js:560] (this=0x266ee106c91 <JS Global Object>#5#)
9: _tickCallback [node.js:415] (this=0x29e7331bb2a1 <a process>#7#)
```

How can I find the source of this infinite loop?

Unfortunately the servers are running in production and are processing many thousands of requests, so it's difficult to give any additional context. The basic function of the servers is to make outbound HTTP requests for other services.

It's worth noting that I don't believe this is caused by a memory leak. The server's memory usage remains constant (and low) during these freeze events, while the CPU spikes to 99%

Another piece of evidence towards the conclusion of an infinite loop is that the event loop itself seems to have stopped. When I put a console.log inside of a setInterval, the server will stop outputting as soon as it freezes.

We have verified that the problem is not caused by expired/corrupted socket connections, by setting the number of max connections to Infinity (which disables their reuse in node.js)

We're using JSONStream 0.7.1 (which includes a default jsonparse version of 0.0.5). We found [this issue](https://github.com/creationix/jsonparse/pull/22) on the JSONStream repo, and tried forking JSONParse and only updating to the newest jsonparse version. It did NOT fix the issue.

Comment: The first message says `toString [buffer.js:~392]`, the problem is at buffer.js line 392

Comment: What could cause an infinite loop though @JonathanS? That source looks pretty innocuous

Comment: Do you have the JSON string itself that's getting serialized to the stream?

Comment: Unfortunately no. The servers are running in production, and they have thousands of events per second going through them, and we haven't found any pattern to the failures, so there's no additional information I can give.

Comment: I would say that it might have some memory leak.. check this blog: http://www.toptal.com/nodejs/debugging-memory-leaks-node-js-applications

Comment: As a tip in the right direction for future debugging purposes: our servers are very configuration-oriented. We listen to changes on the configuration file and the server re-digests it. This allows us to have a config field that makes a debug log function turn from a no-op to actually logging. That way we can have a bunch of `logger.debug` calls in our production code. If you don't care about the "liveness" of this debugging approach, you can have a precompilation step that strips out the debug calls normally unless you're deploying a release candidate to help you debug an issue like this one.

Comment: @fmodos Thanks for the idea! I should have mentioned that it does not appear to be a memory leak, as the memory usage remains constant (and low) during the infinite loop. CPU spikes to 99%. I'll edit the OP to reflect this

Comment: @Vinay we do have extensive logging setup, but unfortunately there's no identifiable pattern that we've noticed yet - request errors are nothing abnormal for us, so it's kind of a needle in a haystack

Comment: Are there to many clients writing to the stream?  Do you have any sort of load balancing in place to spawn new stream handlers as they are needed?  I'm just throwing the idea out there, you could test this by checking if your problem isn't replicated in a test environment with a low frequency of requests, and then simulate more requests to see if the problem is reproduced.  I'd suspect some sort of memory leak or blocking is happening here.

Comment: @Alex thanks for the idea, but I'm fairly certain that the server is in some kind of infinite loop. I'm not sure what you mean by "many clients writing to the stream".

Comment: We have verified that the problem is not caused by expired/corrupted socket connections, by setting the number of max connections to Infinity (which disables their reuse in node.js) @Alex

Comment: Corrupted in which way? How did the corrupted data leak from the socket connection to where you stream this JSON object? At the very least, have you put in additional logging that will make this obvious in the future if it arises again? Distributed systems nerd here. :-)

Comment: The problem is NOT corrupted sockets. I'm just trying to eliminate causes, and I think that's what @Alex was getting at. That was actually one of the first things we considered, even before getting the core dump info.

Comment: I'm glad you ruled that out as an issue, I hope you find the root of the problem soon.

Comment: I initially thought that this might be an issue where you have a circular reference in your JSON structure, but it would appear that JSON.stringify is smart enough to `throw` its toys out of the pram if you do this. Is there any chance you could at least share a section of the code? Otherwise it's going to be much hmming and ahhing. In particular, it would be good to see the flow of what objects are being piped into the stream. I know you mention that its in production and you cant stop it, that's fine, but being able to see how we get to the output stream might help.

Comment: Also, I doubt this is a memory leak; this seems to be an issue with some kind of recursive structure, which would explain why all of your CPU gets consumed.

Comment: I would GREATLY help to know the versions of the packages you are using as well. Until that point there's really not much anyone can do to help. `jsonstream` depends on `jsonparse` and the error occurs at `jsonparse.js:136`, but the current HEAD of `jsonparse.js:136` is a line that couldn't throw an error, so versioning is really important to diagnose this.

Comment: However, ultimately, there just isn't enough information in this error to diagnose your problem - which is probably why no one has responded. We need to at least have your `package.json` `dependencies`.

Comment: @ARedHerring Thanks for the contribution. I'm also suspecting some kind of recursive structure, but it does appear that the crash is happening during toString, rather than Stringify, so I'm not sure how it would be possible. I'll update the OP with some information about package versions

Comment: @ARedHerring Unfortunately there's no easy way to paste a code snippit - the streaming behavior of the servers is rather complicated, and spread across many files.

Comment: That's fine. Your issue appears to be caused [here](https://github.com/creationix/jsonparse/blob/0.0.5/jsonparse.js#L136).

Comment: @ARedHerring Interesting!!! What leads you to that conclusion?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91625/discussion-between-a-red-herring-and-zectbynmo).

Comment: @ZECTBynmo did you consider the point that you are processing too much simultaneous requests and this might be the real cause of the CPU usage? got remember that Node.js creates a new process when you are forwarding the request.

Comment: @fmodos this is actually confirmed due to an infinite loop in jsonparse's code - nothing to do with too many simultaneous requests. The problem here is the actual event loop is stopping, which is indicative of CPU bound issues, not I/O bound ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would appear that your issue is somehow being caused by [this line](https://github.com/creationix/jsonparse/blob/0.0.5/jsonparse.js#L136) of `jsonstream@0.0.5`. While I can't conclusively fix the issue for you without a dump of what is going through the server, this would appear to indicate that your buffer is extremely large.

This would also explain why your servers are locking up (as you mentioned in chat), why the event loop doesn't proceed and why your memory doesn't go up to the sky but your CPU does; what's probably happen here is you're attempting to `toString()` an incredibly large amount of bytes which your hardware simply can't do and it dies.

By all means report back on any further investigation from this lead. I feel it's unavoidable that you're going to have repro the issue on a dev box. It could be as simple as adding some sanity checks to your buffer and making sure it doesn't go above a certain size.

The above section of code is only hit if `n <= 128`, so if you're using signed characters (such as Unicode) or signed bytes then you might actually encounter this issue in normal function... might be something to consider!

Comment: Thanks again! I've managed to verify that we are indeed looping at that line. The direct reason for the infinite loop is that this.bytes_in_sequence is 0, so we never increment the counter i, so we're stuck. I haven't figured out the root cause of that 0, but...progress!!

Comment: That seems like a strange bug. The section I linked is only reached if `bytes_in_sequence <= 0` and it will actually decrease `i` by 1 - that is what causes the infinite loop. You *may* want to check if this is logged as an issue on jsonparse's github. Are you *positive* that you tried a newer version of jsonparse? I mean, this version of jsonparse is 2 years old.

Comment: In the end, there were two separate but related issues. First, the version of JSONStream we were using included jsonparse@0.0.5, which was before the fix mentioned in the OP.

Once we applied that fix, the server was still freezing, because the fix had addressed ASCII characters between 128 and 194, but not characters above 244. 

tldr: a specific ascii character was causing an infinite loop inside of jsonparse

Comment: What a very intriguing bug :P

Comment: @ZECTBynmo seems [we're not the first ones](https://github.com/creationix/jsonparse/issues/17) to have this issue. Just no one opened a PR.

Comment: Yeah, but I believe we are the first ones to see the issue for characters above 244. I wonder what caused our system to encounter these weird characters? My guess is that some third party system (we talk to a lot of them) must have changed their API to include those characters as unescaped content.

Comment: Full resolution to the issue thanks in large part to @ARedHerring - thanks again!